# Best way to remove/merge duplicates in this list?

Tags: python, list, merge

I got a list which is built up like this:

```
item_list = [
    [ObjectB, 9],
    [ObjectA, 2],
    [ObjectB, 5],
    [ObjectC, 8],
    [ObjectA, 7]
]
```

As you can see ObjectA and ObjectB are two times in this list. The left column defines which kind of item it is, the right how often I need it. Therefore I'd like to get a result like this:

```
item_list = [
    [ObjectB, 14],
    [ObjectA, 9],
    [ObjectC, 8],
]
```

`[ObjectB, 9]` and `[ObjectB, 5]` got merged together to `[ObjectB, 14]` and so did the `ObjectA` occurrences.
What is the best way to achieve this? I tried several solutions but I feel like there's an really easy and efficient one.

Comment: Try converting it into a dictionary

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Obviously, a dictionary will come handy for your problem:

```
d = defaultdict(int)
for k, v in item_list:  # unwrapping credits to @clemtoy
    d[k] += v
result = [[k, v] for k, v in d.iteritems()]
```

So what you do first is create a `defaultdict`, using `int` as a factory method. This means that if you try to access any key in the dictionary that does not exist, you will get `0`.

Next you start filling your dictionary, by incrementing the values for the keys. If the key is not yet in the dictionary, you will, start from `0`.

Now finally to transform back to the structure you want, you need the last line - list comprehension. And your `result` will be:

```
[[ObjectA, 9], [ObjectB, 14], [ObjectC, 8]]
```

Moreover, if you need it sorted, go ahead:

```
result = sorted(result, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)))
```

This will sort your `result` in descending order, using the second subelement of each element.

Comment: Nice! But `for k, v in item_list: d[k] += v` would be the cutest in my view!

Comment: Worked out perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
ObjectA = "hello"
ObjectB = "cruel"
ObjectC = "world"

item_list = [
    [ObjectB, 9],
    [ObjectA, 2],
    [ObjectB, 5],
    [ObjectC, 8],
    [ObjectA, 7]
]

sum = {}
for item in item_list:
    sum[item[0]] = sum.get(item[0], 0) + item[1]
print(sum)
```

> {'world': 8, 'cruel': 14, 'hello': 9}